# How to summarize the elements in a complex object?

Tags: r

I have a very complex S4 object (output from a [lavaan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/lavaan.pdf) model) which has slots within slots within slots and variables (`$`) at the deepest level of each of the deepest slots. How do I extract and store the `object.size`(and potentially other functions like `length` and `dim` and the object name) of every element within this object so that I can compare it to another object of the same class?

I have tried storing the output from `str(obj)` and `unclass(obj)` and then manipulating the output to extract the information I want, but it's turning out to be very tedious. Looping over names is equally difficult. Is there a way to "flatten" the object into a list? Is there a recursive function anyone can think of to repeatedly dig into each slot?

**Edit**

Here's an example, using the `lavaan` package I referenced above, though ideally the solution shouldn't be dependent on the specific object class and could work across classes:

```
library(lavaan)
model <- '
  # measurement model
    ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
    dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
    dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
  # regressions
    dem60 ~ ind60
    dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
  # residual correlations
    y1 ~~ y5
    y2 ~~ y4 + y6
    y3 ~~ y7
    y4 ~~ y8
    y6 ~~ y8
'         
fit <- sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)
```

The object `fit` contains many slots and objects inside. I can, of course, extract information from a particular element like `object.size(fit@Data@X[[1]])`, but I'm looking for a generalized solution. The challenge is that I want to extract the same information about each element, regardless of its "depth".

Thanks!

Comment: Without some sample data it's hard to comment but have you taken a look at rapply?

Comment: sample data can be easily obtained from the examples of the corresponding package, the real question is which slots is @dmp interested in

Comment: i was trying to point you at some helpful functions, but my answer is getting downvoted for no apparent reason. if you would be kind to post which slots exactly are you interested in from the object - i would gladly post some code using these functions that extracts what you want.

Comment: I will edit my question. I don't understand the downvotes either.

Answer (score -1):

seems like `purrr` package might be of help here, especially functions like `flatten`, `transpose`, `map` / `at_depth` - combined with char vectors as input you can easily extract stuff from deeply nested lists. for example, you could write down the "extractor" functions that you need separatly, then store them all in a list and use `invoke` (also from `purrr`) with your object as sole arg or `invoke_map` on many such objects.

**Edit**
Here is some code to help you extract `object.size(fit@Data@X[[1]])` from one or many `lavaan` objects. Since the slots you are interested in, in practice are most probably at different depths, my guess is that there is no easy general solution.
The idea is that once you know the exact elements you are interested in - it is fairly straightforward to code up some helper functions to manipulate single/multiple such objects. The functions that I mentioned above provide friendly shortcuts for achieving this.
Let me know if i can be of further help.

```
  library("lavaan")
  library("tidyverse")

  model <- '
  # measurement model
  ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
  dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
  dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
  # regressions
  dem60 ~ ind60
  dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
  # residual correlations
  y1 ~~ y5
  y2 ~~ y4 + y6
  y3 ~~ y7
  y4 ~~ y8
  y6 ~~ y8
  '         

  # say you have 3 different models
  fit1 <- sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)
  fit2 <- sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)
  fit3 <- sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)

  # S4 objects have function slot() function for accessing so 
  object.size(fit@Data@X[[1]]) 
  # becomes
  slot(slot(fit, "Data"), "X")[[1]]

  # since fit is an S4 object - you have to wrap it up 
  # in a list to manipulate it easier.
  # above code becomes : 
  list(fit1) %>% 
    map(~ slot(., "Data")) %>% 
    map(~ slot(., "X")) %>%  
    flatten %>% 
    map(object.size)

  # wrap up the above code in a helper function ...
  extr_obj_size <- function(lavaan_fit) {
    list(lavaan_fit) %>% 
      map(~ slot(., "Data")) %>% 
      map(~ slot(., "X")) %>%  
      map(object.size) 
  }

  extr_obj_size(fit1)

  # which you can further wrap up in a function that operates 
  # on a vector of such objects
  extr_multiple_obj_size <- function(vec_lavaan_fits) {
    vec_lavaan_fits %>% 
      map(extr_obj_size) %>% 
      flatten

  }

  c(fit,fit2,fit3) %>% extr_multiple_obj_size
```

**Edit2**

I don't know how helpful would the following code be *in general* but i jumbled up something that, given that you know the name of the slot you are interested in - would check at depth 1 and 2 and return you the corresponding value.

```
fit <- sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)
slot_of_interest <- "eq.constraints"

# slot names at depth 1
depth1 <- names(getSlots("lavaan"))
# slot names at depth 2
depth2 <- depth1 %>% map(~ slotNames(slot(fit,.)))

# helper fun to check if a slot name of interest is inside a slot
in_slot <- function(x) slot_of_interest %in% x

# so if its at depth 1 - then just map slot()-function with that name
if (slot_of_interest %in% depth1) {
  list(fit1) %>% map(~slot(., slot_of_interest))
} else {
  # otherwise you would need to detect at which index at depth2 does this name appear
  index1 <- depth2 %>% detect_index(in_slot)
  # and map first the slot-name at that index - then the corresponding slot of interest
  list(fit1) %>% map(~ slot(., depth1[index1])) %>% map(~ slot(., slot_of_interest))
}
```

Comment: downvote? at least a comment as to why would be helpful to expand my answer. im trying to be helpful